# How to execute arbitrary key sequence {count} times

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

The problem I wish to solve, first of all, is when you want do do the same editing on multiple lines, but they are not aligned so you can't use `Ctrl + V`, maybe the lines are not even adjacent. In these cases I tend to use `q` to record, and then I reproduce with `@`, but I would like to know if I can do both at the same time.

I want to know if it is possible to craft a more practical and volatile version of the recording feature (`:h recording`).

Ideally, I would like to press:

- `{count}` as any number, becomes 1 by default
- `[` key
- Any key sequence, for example, `$F)i, 0<esc>2j`
- `]` key

And the behaviour I would like to see is the key sequence I pressed being simulated `{count}` times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish that with a mapping that stores the count (for example, in a buffer-local, script-local or even global variable) and start recording a macro (say `qa`), and then a second mapping for `]` that stops recording the macro and executes it the number of times passed as the count (minus one, since the recording itself also counts!)

In short:

```
nnoremap <silent> [ :<C-U>let b:recording_count = v:count1<CR>qa
nnoremap <expr> ] 'q' . (b:recording_count > 1 ? (b:recording_count - 1).'@a' : '')
```

This is not super robust, you might run into issues if you use `]` before `[` or otherwise while you're not recording...

You can maybe come up with something a bit more advanced, for example by installing the mapping for the end of recording just when you start recording. You could use `q` for the end mapping in that case, since that's how you otherwise end a recording.

This is also using a fixed register (`@a`) which could also be addressed (e.g. using `v:register` to allow the user to pick a different one.)

In general though, I'm not sure I like this idea that much, given it makes it hard to fix a mistake during recording the macro, and isn't really gaining much, since all you need to do is do the `(count-1)@a` at the end of recording anyway...

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to use the expression register `=` together with the macro replay operator `@`.

When you type `@=`, Vim will let you enter a Vimscript expression (i.e. a string) and will execute that string as a macro. You can pass `@=` a count and it will repeat the execution `{count}` times.

In your case, start with, say, `7@=` (to run it seven times), then in the prompt enter `"$F)i, 0\<esc>2j"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will execute that string as a macro seven times. Note that you need the quotes `"..."` to turn the expression into a string, and that you can use key names such as `<esc>`, but you need to escape them with a backslash so that Vim knows it's a special character (this escaping of key names only works in double quoted strings, not single quoted `'...'` ones.)